# Issue with limit of strategy.exit

Tags: pine-script

Limit and Stop are not working properly. Any idea why?
The picture show an example (blu lines are take profit and stop loss)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woNdq.png)
Here's the script:

```
tp = strategy.position_avg_price * (1.15)
sl = strategy.position_avg_price * (0.90)
plot(tp)
plot(strategy.position_avg_price)
plot(sl)

if (t <= -15)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long, when = window())
    strategy.exit ("My Long Exit Id", limit = tp, stop = sl, when = window())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like first of all you need to write the same ID in `strategy.entry` and `strategy.exit`.

Try to convert your `tp` and `sl` to tick's:

```
TPfixed = input.float(1, "Take profit", minval=0.1, maxval=100,step=0.1)
SLfixed = input.float(0.5, "Stop loss", minval=0.1, maxval=100, step=0.1)
tp = (strategy.position_avg_price*(TPfixed/100))/syminfo.mintick
sl = (strategy.position_avg_price * (SLfixed/100)/syminfo.mintick
strategy.exit("Close","Long", loss=sl, profit=tp, when=strategy.position_size>0)
```

Pay attention in the function you need to use the arguments `loss` and `profit`

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your improvement. Finally the big issue was the first If condition. Adding and else after strategy.entry solved. Enjoy the day!

Comment: You're welcome! If it helps, mark question as answered.